# Data warehouse star schema

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a lesson called Data warehousing in there is a section called Star Scheme model

Can anyone explain the meaning of star schema in data warehouse concept,
i tried in the net but i could't found any answer. its in my Degree syllabus but i cant understand it.

So, in my report/cubes i need to know (in a period):

1 How many Newsletter lead to a Sale,

2 How many Newsletter have been generated.

Where should i place the generate_date of Newsletter? If i place it in FACT table, but if this Newsletter did not lead to a Sale, there will be no date in FACT table.

If i place it on Newsletter and join it to Time, i would be breaking the Star schema?

How do i solve this :S

I have many other cases that is the same question, like client join_date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Star Schema is a Model,

Ex:-
Factual data belonging to an organization activity are stored in a central table. this central table is surrounded by a set of reference tables. each reference table has a one to many ralationship with the central table